# Switch web.config transformations in production?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, configuration, web-config, production

I know this is a long shot.

What I'm hoping is that there is a way to deploy multiple copies of a Web.config file to the production environment as part of packaged code (let's call them `Web.config.prod` and `Web.config.prodTest`) so that regression testers can test on a disconnected production server (using `prodTest`) in a different namespace (e.g., prodtest.com) prior to making it go live (say, using `prod` on prod.com) without doing two separate deployments.

Short of making a PowerShell script to swap out the values, I can't think of a good way to do this. Every project I've seen so far has a single .config file made as part of the build.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some settings (the ones most likely to change) you can put both in the web.config and have the code select the appropriate configuration to use.

```
<connectionstrings>
    <add name="ProductionDatabase" DataSource="production-db.mycompany.com" />
    <add name="TestDatabase" DataSource="test-db.mycompany.com" />
</connectionstrings>
```

However, if you don't want to do that, then you are welcome to write your own build/deployment scripts and have them do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks @mason, unfortunately the code base is too large to put test switches everywhere (the actual scenario is much more complicated than what I described). I think we are just going to have to have QA test in a different environment and have a different set of transforms.

Comment: @lokalife code size isn't your problem. Proper separation of concerns is. There should only be *one* place in the code where settings are retrieved. You shouldn't have them spread out. For example, don't embed connection string names in your code behinds or controllers. Instead, grab the values at at app startup and use them to initialize repositories in your data layer or store them in the `Application` variable.

Comment: You're not kidding. SoC is a major problem with our solution. I wish it was all my code to change. :D